# How to check the HTTP response returned by the server in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http

i am authenticating user based on userName and password.If password is not correct i have to inform the user regarding the same. I am new to angular 4. Please help.

Angular side code,

```
postAdminUsertoDashboard( user: User) : Observable<Number>{
    let dashboard_login: string ="/xyz/dashboard-login/login";
    let body = "userName=" + user.getUserName + "&password=" + user.getPassword;
    return this.http.post(this.base_url,body)
    .map(success => success.status).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

server side ,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> authenticateUser(@RequestParam("userName") String userName, @RequestParam("password") String password) 
    {
        final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminUserController.class);
        AdminUserDomain adminUser = adminUserService.authenticate(userName);
        if(adminUser == null) {
            ExceptionDomain domainException = new ExceptionDomain(1001,"User not found",null);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(domainException, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        if(!password.equals(adminUser.getPassword())) {
            ExceptionDomain domainException = new ExceptionDomain(1002,"Password is incorrect",null);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(domainException, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(adminUser, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
```

Comment: Send data in formdata and add headers to your request.

Answer (score 0):

For **post request**, you have to send params in formdata.

postDataApi(username, password){
    var headers = new Headers();

```
var url = 'login';
let input = new FormData();
input.append("username", username);
input.append("password", password);

return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+url, input, {headers:headers})
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: how do i return the HTTP response for the post request?

Comment: Replace your .map function with below .map function.
.map(response => {
                  var r = response.json();
                  localStorage.setItem('accessToken', r.accessToken); 
                  return r;
                })

Comment: How to validate this access Token?

Comment: accessToken is just parameter we store in local storage at the time of login and delete at the time of logout. So, whenever you are accessing any route check whether localStorage contains accessToken parameter or not.
You can *https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards* link.